# Prove the inequalities using the basic properties of integrals.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

> Prove the inequality using the basic properties of integrals:
> $\int_{a}^{b} \sin^2(x) dx< \int_{a}^{b} |\sin x|dx$ for $a<b$

At first I integrated $\sin^2(x)$, and then I integrated |sin x|. For $\sin x >0$ the integral is $\cos x$ but for $\sin x < 0$ the integral is $-\cos x$.
If $a$ or $b$ were given it'd be easier since I can integrate $|\sin x|$ based on the limits but I'm lost here.

> Another question is to prove that: $\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2}< 1$

Here it didn't take me long to realise that the integral can't be expressed using elementary functions, so I don't know what to do?

Edit: I think I can analyse this and come to a conclusion using one of property of integral. For x in [0,1] $e^-x^2$ is always smaller than the constant a in this interval, therefore the integral will be too. I need to know if I'm right and also if there is another way of doing it.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\int_a^b|\sin x|\,\mathrm dx$?

Comment: it is fixed now, thanks for reminding me, I forgot to add "_"

Comment: **Hint :** Prove that for every $x$, $\sin^2(x) \leq |\sin(x)|$, and then, integrate.

Comment: For the second question, $e^{-x^2}\leq1$ on $[0,1]$. The maximum of $e^{-x^2}$ occurs when $x=0$.

Comment: You'll also need to use the fact that TheSilverDoes' inequality is strict on some open subinterval of $[a,b]$.

Comment: Yeah I  got that tip but I still can't don't know how to do that. I mean how do I prove than $sin^(x)<= |sin(x)|$?

Comment: Use that $-1\leqslant \sin x\leqslant 1$. What happens when you square a number between $-1$ and $1$?

Comment: I got it since |sinx|<1, when it is squared it will always be less than |sinx|.

Answer (score 1):

For any $0<y<1$, we have that $y<\sqrt y$. For $y=\sin^2 x$, we will get  $$\sin^2 x<\sqrt{\sin^2 x}=|\sin x|.$$
Now integrate over $(0,1)$.

For the second part, by the Mean Value Theorem for integrals, there exists some $c\in(a,b)$ such that $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=f(c)(b-a),$$ which here becomes $$\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}dx=e^{-c^2}(1-0)$$ for some $c\in(0,1).$ But for any $c\in(0,1), e^{-c^2}<1$, so $\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}dx<1$.